# What are the conventions for classes named "base" and "basic" in the C++ Standard Library?

Tags: c++, naming-conventions, std

Several classes in the C++ Standard Library have "base" or "basic" in their name. Examples are `std::ios_base` and `std::basic_ios`. I have a rough sense of the conventions but I'd like to see them spelled out and I can't find a resource that does that.

For classes with "base" or "basic" in the name, what are the conventions concerning class hierarchies, templating, and typedefs?

Comment: The `basic_string` class is specialized as `string` for `char` and `wstring` for `wchar_t`. I think the `base` class is just ... a base class. It's a bit unnatural, collecting stuff that turned out to be needed in most all derived classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::basic_foo` is a class template for a class that handles text in some way and can be specialized for various character types.

`std::foo` is a typedef for `std::basic_foo<char>`.

`std::wfoo` is a typedef for `std::basic_foo<wchar_t>`.

Examples: `std::basic_ios`, `std::basic_string`, `std::basic_regex`.

On the other hand, `std::ios_base` is a special case. There's no convention that says that base classes should be named in that way, and I'm not aware of any other examples. I imagine they just couldn't come up with a better name.

Comment: `ios_base` is an old name, 20 years old or so. The C++ standard tries to avoid breaking old code, even if a better name could be invented.

Answer (score 0):

Definitions.

Base: the bottom support of anything; that on which a thing stands or rests.

Basic: of, relating to, or forming a base or basis; fundamental; underlying; elementary or simple; excluding additions or extras.

So a base class is a foundation and a basic string is one that has not been specialised. Seems sensible to me.